# Flutter: how to handle a JSON that has list of list of objects?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am creating a flutter project and I do an HTTP GET request where I get back the following JSON:

```
[
     {
        "type": "Type one",
        "elements": [{
                "name": "Type one 1 name",
                "code": "TYPEONE_1"
            },
            {
                "name": "Type one 2 name",
                "code": "TYPEONE_2"
            },
            {
                "name": "Type one 3 name",
                "code": "TYPEONE_3"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "type": "Type two",
        "elements": [{
                "name": "Type two 1 name",
                "code": "TYPETWO_1"
            },
            {
                "name": "Type two 2 name",
                "code": "TYPETWO_2"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I created these classes:

```
class Type {
  String type;
  List<Element> elements;
}

class Element {
  String name;
  String code;
}
```

But from here how to decode the JSON response into a list of `Type`?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use this [site](https://app.quicktype.io) to create classes according to your JSON data, then you can use their constructors to convert your data into objects.

Answer (score 1):

This model is for your response:

```dart
class Model {
    List<Type> el;
}

class Type {
    String type;
    List<Element> elements;
}

class Element {
    String name;
    String code;
}
```